# Entity Framework Returning Extra unwanted Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework in my project. There are 3 tables in the `.edmx` model file:

Table `Category master` with these two columns:

```
* Category_id (int, primary key)
* Category_Name (nvarchar)
```

There are two other tables `Sub_Category_Master` and `Question_master`. Both have a FK `Category_id` which is linked to the **PK** of `category_Master`.

My problem is when I access the data

```
dt = context.Category_Master.ToList().ToDataTable();
```

Than it should return data from `Category_Master` table only, but instead of this I am getting  two additional columns `Question_Master` and `Sub_Category_master` with values of type `System.Collection`:

[image]

It is causing problem as this is an api and getting failed due to unwanted values

Although I have a workaround for this by using below approach

```
dt = context.Category_Master.Select(x => new
            {
                Category_id = x.Category_id,
                Category_Name = x.Category_Name
            }).ToList().ToDataTable();
```

This returns only required values, but in case in future if we need to add additional columns in table than adjustment for new column will be required here in this case which I don't want to do, neither I want to use ado.net with `select * from table` statement. So how can I get only data for category master using Entity Framework like below snapshot

[image]

**Update one**

Below is the auto generated class of `Category_master.cs`

```
public partial class Category_Master
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Category_Master()
    {
        this.Question_Master = new HashSet<Question_Master>();
        this.Sub_Category_Master = new HashSet<Sub_Category_Master>();
    }

    public int Category_id { get; set; }
    public string Category_Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Question_Master> Question_Master { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Sub_Category_Master> Sub_Category_Master { get; set; }
}
```

If I comment out `virtual ICollection` of other classes like below, then will it affect somewhere in my code? Or table relationship?

```
 public partial class Category_Master
 {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Category_Master()
        {
            //this.Question_Master = new HashSet<Question_Master>();
            //this.Sub_Category_Master = new HashSet<Sub_Category_Master>();
        }

        public int Category_id { get; set; }
        public string Category_Name { get; set; }

        //[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        //public virtual ICollection<Question_Master> Question_Master { get; set; }
        //[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        //public virtual ICollection<Sub_Category_Master> Sub_Category_Master { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to deal with AutoMapper and DTOs, you can use [OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/):

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Data.OData

```
public class CategoryController : ODataController
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _ctx;
    public CategoryController(YourDbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }        

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Category_Master> Get()
    {
       return _ctx.Category_Master;
    }
}
```

Request to select Category_ID and Category_Name only:

> GET /odata/Category?$select=Category_Name,Category_Id

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning an Entity, return DTO object:

```
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

You can use **AutoMapper** to map entity to DTO classes, something like that:

```
CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>()
    .ForMember(q => q.CategoryName, w => w.MapFrom(e => e.Category_Name))
    .ForMember(q => q.CategoryId, w => w.MapFrom(e => e.Category_Id));
```

By utilizing [Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) you can query the database in a following way:

```
context.Category_Master.ProjectToList<CategoryDTO>();
```

Comment: There is already class(under edmx file) with same signature as CategoryDto , witrh this approach I have to duplicate class for every table